# russian character in recode_string php

Tags: php

I have a little problem with russian characters and recode_string function.

```
$str = "И в этом вся моя вина (And Only That école & Can Be My Blame)";
echo recode_string("UTF-8..flat", $string);
```

Give me "d Only That ecole & Can Be My Blame)" instead of (and Only That ecole & Can Be My Blame)

Can anyone help me with this problem ? 
Thanks

Comment: To be less sarcastic - it's a built-in PHP function, check out the manual.

Comment: Mihai, you probably don't have this function available neither. You probably have php yelling a fatal error saying that you call an undefined function. Reason is that, to have it, you should compile php with a specific parameter to have the relevant module enabled. See http://nc.php.net/manual/en/recode.installation.php

Comment: recode_string can be wonky at times, if you can, try using [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
mb_convert_encoding('И в этом вся моя вина (And Only That école & Can Be My Blame)', 'windows-1251', 'utf8');
```

but u must know change windows-1251 on something else i think

or try `iconv()` as *donutdan4114 said*

Answer (score 0):

You use **$string** in the second line, but defined **$str** in the first line.